# Speed up playback of a video with a video editor

Tags: audio, youtube, vlc, playback, video-editing

Recently, I discover that my tutorial videos could be seen at 1.5x playback speed without losses in quality (they are actually better to see, as I normally speak slowly). My problem is that if I change the speed of the video when using a video editor, like Kdenlive, the audio becomes distorted and turns into a mess (higher pitch, I believe).

How could I obtain the same quality as VLC "playback fast" and Youtube "playback speed 1.5" for the audio track? I'm a layman in audio/video editing, so I'm also satisfied with partial answers, like the identification of which terms I should search for in this case.

Comment: You could use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) like this `playback_speed=1.25;
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -filter:v "setpts=PTS/${playback_speed}" -filter:a "atempo=${playback_speed}" OUTPUT_FILE`
`

Comment: [FFMPEG wiki:How to speed up / slow down a video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video)

Comment: @fdcpp your comment could be the answer for this question, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to take your audio track and use something like Sound Forge to automatically remove silence. Just be sure to add a pad to that (built into sound forge) otherwise the speech will sound way to chopped and fast.
Aside from that, you could also use Vegas to (then) chop the video to keep pace with your new speech rate. Vegas is a video editing program that is best for this kind of down and dirty editing.